Keyring login gone wrong. Ubuntu 24.04
Ok, so I was trying to stop having to login to my keyring when I start up Ubuntu 24.04. On restart I find that my keyring was still being required, but that the old keyring password didn't work.(Vivaldi).
I don't mind reinstalling Ubuntu, but there must be an easier way? Seahorse has an option to delete the "Chrome Safe storage" password, I'm guessing I should do that and replace it with a new one?
thanks

If your login password has changed and the keyring password didn't update automatically, you can reset it so both passwords match, making the login process smoother.
Press the Super key (the Windows key) and search for "Passwords and Keys." Open the keys application.
Now change the Keyring Password. On the left side of the window, find the "Login" keyring. Right-click on it and choose "Change Password."
When asked, enter the old keyring password.
Set a new password for the keyring, and it's best to make it the same as your login password so it unlocks automatically when you log in.
This way, your keyring password will match your login password, so you won't need to enter it every time you log into Ubuntu.
By doing this, you prevent the need to repeatedly type in the keyring password, and you can set it up to automatically unlock when you log in.
